# Applescript: Getting list of selected layers on Photoshop

Tags: applescript

I am creating an AppleScript where I need to do something to the selected layers on Photoshop.

How do I get the list of the selected layers on Photoshop even if the selected layers are inside groups?

I don't have code to show right now because it all starts by having the list of selected layers, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selected layers is not a property in JavaScript's `artLayer` object and selected is not an property of the `layer` object in AppleScript either. However we can work with AM in PhotoShop and use actions and it's descriptor result to get the selected layers. Because the layers may need to swift depending on whether there is an background layer or not we first create an array with selected indices (code is based on [this post](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1161110?tstart=0)) and after that we resolve the names of the layers.

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS6"
    tell document 1
        set selectedLayers to paragraphs of (do javascript "
var typeDocument        = stringIDToTypeID('document');
var typeItemIndex       = stringIDToTypeID('itemIndex');
var typeLayer           = stringIDToTypeID('layer');
var typeName            = stringIDToTypeID('name');
var typeOrdinal         = stringIDToTypeID('ordinal');
var typeProperty        = stringIDToTypeID('property');
var typeTarget          = stringIDToTypeID('targetEnum');
var typeTargetLayers    = stringIDToTypeID('targetLayers');
var selectedLayers  = new Array();
var actionRef           = new ActionReference();

actionRef.putEnumerated(typeDocument, typeOrdinal, typeTarget);
var actionDesc = executeActionGet(actionRef);

if(actionDesc.hasKey(typeTargetLayers) ){
    actionDesc = actionDesc.getList(typeTargetLayers);
    var c = actionDesc.count

    for(var i=0;i<c;i++){
        try{
            activeDocument.backgroundLayer;
            selectedLayers.push(actionDesc.getReference( i ).getIndex() );
        }catch(e){
            selectedLayers.push(actionDesc.getReference( i ).getIndex()+1 );
        }
    }
}else{
    var actionRef = new ActionReference();
    actionRef.putProperty(typeProperty , typeItemIndex);
    actionRef.putEnumerated(typeLayer, typeOrdinal, typeTarget);
    try{
        activeDocument.backgroundLayer;
        selectedLayers.push( executeActionGet(actionRef).getInteger(typeItemIndex)-1);
    }catch(e){
        selectedLayers.push( executeActionGet(actionRef).getInteger(typeItemIndex));
    }
}

var selectedLayerNames = new Array();

for (var a in selectedLayers){
    var ref = new ActionReference();   
    ref.putIndex(typeLayer, Number(selectedLayers[a]) );  
    var layerName = executeActionGet(ref).getString(typeName);
        selectedLayerNames.push(layerName);  
}

selectedLayerNames.join('\\n');
")

    end tell
end tell
```